# Passing Array parameter to SQLiteObject.executeSql()

Tags: sqlite, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to pass an array parameter to the function executeSql of SQLiteObject in ionic to make it as a value for my sql query.

For example

```
var sqlQuery: string = "SELECT * FROM Property WHERE ID IN (?) AND Status = ?"
var ids: number[] = [123, 321, 456];
```

and I'm trying to pass it here,

```
var db: SQLiteObject
db.executeSql(sqlQuery, [ids, 0])
```

So basically I want to insert all the values of **ids** to the **IN** operator and 0 for Status. But I think the SQL interprets it differently.

I tried to pass it as a string `db.executeSql(sqlQuery, [ids.toString(), 0])` to remove the unnecessary characters and such. But still it doesn't return anything.

**NOTE**
I know I need it to enclose to a promise or something, but I just sliced it and summarize it to remove the unnecessary codes. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to search all over but still can't find a definite answer, I just invent a work around for it by doing this method.

```
var ids: number[] = [123, 321, 456];
var sqlQuery: string = "SELECT * FROM Property WHERE ID IN (" + ids.toString() + ") AND Status = ?";
```

And pass it to `executeSql` function

```
var db: SQLiteObject
db.executeSql(sqlQuery, [0]);
```

This is just a work around. I'll still wait for a better solution. Thanks!